# Humanoid harem - Kissing makes them stronger

Tags: sekirei

So there was this anime I watched but never finished and I forgot the name of it.

The anime was a harem, and the story was about humanoids fighting each other until only 1 survived. All the humanoids were girls and had the power to become stronger if they kissed a person.

A few things I remember:

- Humanoids 1-9 (possibly 1-10) were stronger than the rest.
- At one point, the main character helps a man and his humanoid escape the city (a forbidden act) which was heavily guarded with a few of the 1-9 humanoids.
- The main character's sister had a humanoid that was trying to find it's sister, which turned out to be the main character's humanoid.

I'm sorry if this is confusing but it's probably the most simple way I can put all this down. I'm 99% the girls were some type of humanoid or something but I'm not 100% if the term in the anime was humanoid.

Answer (score 8):

Probably [**Sekirei**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/4063/Sekirei).

> the story was about humanoids

Which are called "Sekirei".

> All the humanoids were girls

Most, but not all (Shiina is male; Homura may also be). Equal-opportunity fanservice!

> the main character

Generic McProtagonist-kun.

> helps a man and his humanoid escape the city

Shigi with his Sekirei, Kuno.

> the main character's sister had a humanoid that was trying to find her sister which was the main character's humanoid

sister = Yukari; her Sekirei = Shiina; Shiina's sister = Kusano; Kusano's "master" (Ashikabi) = McProtagonist-kun.

Comment: Definitely Sekirei. They're fighting until only one Sekirei is left, and get stronger when they kiss their Ashikabi. The single-digits (1 - 9) are more powerful than the rest too. Shiina isn't the only guy though; there's a single digit who's also a guy, and quite a huge one too.